# Performing Poorly in Qualify Exam

Tags: phd

I just finished my qualify exam, and I think I performed very bad. My advisor even said it was not up to par. I am not sure if I will pass or not, since my advisor also said they might pass me, if the committee thinks that my research is good enough to compensate for my mistakes.

If I fail, I can retake it one more time. But the pressure would be enormous.

I feel horrible and cannot stop thinking about it. Any suggestions? I did try to distract myself, which led me here.

Comment: Just an update, I passed! Thank god! My advisor said the research project probably contributed greatly to my pass. I was thinking maybe COVID also played a role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get through the comprehensive it's helpful to know every single PhD student stresses over these exams. When I took mine you were only given 2 tries so the pressure was on. I have yet to meet a single PhD that made it through the qualifying exams that thought they were anything more than a worthless distraction. You're in a PhD program to learn to be an independent researcher not a test taker!

It's best not to think about it. Your qualifying exams are more of a test of your ability to study hard for several subjects and test on them. Some universities do not even require them anymore. If you do pass don't worry about your scores as they will have very little effect on your future trajectory. As an example, many fellow PhD students in my class were on the edge of failing the qualifiers and ended up succeeding in the program over all. If you don't pass you will know where you went wrong and can study hard. Unfortunately this is a major time sink and stressor for all PhD students and often it can determine whether you get priority for funding. Take it easy and as cliche at it is - just try to relax.

Comment: Thanks! I just slept 2 hours yesterday, can't stop thinking about it. I will try to do something that distracts me today.